# Multi tenancy and opentelemetry

Tags: elasticsearch, multi-tenant, open-telemetry

I am using opentelemetry (with elastic search 8.3.2 as backend) in a java spring boot application which is a multi tenant application.
I would like to keep trace data for each tenant isolated in its own index in elastic search
What is the best way to achieve this using opentelemetry ?

I tried using the following approach, but looks like ElasticsearchSpanExporter is deprecated

```
  @Bean
    public SpanExporter otelElasticsearchExporter() {
        return ElasticsearchSpanExporter.builder()
                .setEndpoint(elasticsearchEndpoint)
                .setCompression(Compression.GZIP)
                .setIndex(exporterProperties.getSpan().getSpanName() + "-{tenant-id}")
                .build();
    }
```

Next I tried following approach, but RestHighLevelClient is not supported for elastic search 8.3.2

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
@Bean
    public SpanExporter otelElasticsearchExporter(RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient) {
        return new SpanExporter() {
            @Override
            public SpanExporterResult export(Collection<SpanData> spanDataList) {
                BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest();
                spanDataList.forEach(spanData -> {
                    bulkRequest.add(
                            new IndexRequest("your_index_name")
                                    .source(spanDataToJson(spanData), XContentType.JSON)
                    );
                });
                try {
                    BulkResponse bulkResponse = elasticsearchClient.bulk(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
                    if (bulkResponse.hasFailures()) {
                        return SpanExporterResult.FAILURE;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return SpanExporterResult.FAILURE;
                }
                return SpanExporterResult.SUCCESS;
            }
```

I see that if I use the setResource method while creating a trace provider, my traces go into a separate index for each tenant. Not sure if this is a good approach though.

```
SdkTracerProvider tracerProvider =
                SdkTracerProvider.builder()
                        .addSpanProcessor(BatchSpanProcessor.builder(otlpExporter).build())
                        .setResource(Resource.getDefault().merge(tenantId))
                        .build();
```

What is a preferred approach to keep trace data isolated per tenant ?

Answer (score 0):

How do you consume your tracing data? Is it through Elastic APM, or are you using Elasticsearch just as a persistence layer with a different observability tool on top?

The exporting of span data will look different depending on the question above.

If you are using Elastic APM, this [is the documentation for exporting OTel data to Elastic APM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/guide/8.8/open-telemetry.html).

In the latter case, you can use your second approach with the [Java API Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/indexing-bulk.html) instead of the RestHighLevelClient. With that approach you can control which index the spans will be written to.

Comment: I am using elastic APM and kibana dashboard